# Maven nexus could not resolve juniper-contrail-api

Tags: maven, repository, nexus, juniper-network-connect

am trying to install some code on my workstation using an own remote repository using Nexus. Some of the projects can be deployed and installed correctly. However, there is a project which some dependencies cannot be resolved.

This is the log:

```
[INFO] Building Apache CloudStack Plugin - Network Juniper Contrail 4.5.3-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://192.168.1.109:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/net/juniper/contrail/juniper-contrail-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://192.168.1.109:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/net/juniper/contrail/juniper-contrail-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/juniper-contrail-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] The POM for net.juniper.contrail:juniper-contrail-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://192.168.1.109:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.1/commons-exec-1.1.pom
Downloaded: http://192.168.1.109:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.1/commons-exec-1.1.pom (11 KB at 456.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://192.168.1.109:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/net/juniper/contrail/juniper-contrail-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/juniper-contrail-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Downloading: http://192.168.1.109:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.1/commons-exec-1.1.jar
Downloaded: http://192.168.1.109:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.1/commons-exec-1.1.jar (52 KB at 2332.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Developer Tools - Checkstyle Configuration  SUCCESS [5.957s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack ................................. SUCCESS [7.994s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Maven Conventions Parent ........ SUCCESS [1.824s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Framework - Managed Context ..... SUCCESS [3.565s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Utils ........................... SUCCESS [19.943s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Framework ....................... SUCCESS [0.056s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Framework - Event Notification .. SUCCESS [7.477s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Framework - Configuration ....... SUCCESS [3.243s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack API ............................. SUCCESS [12.763s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Framework - REST ................ SUCCESS [2.796s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Framework - IPC ................. SUCCESS [3.335s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Cloud Engine .................... SUCCESS [0.036s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Cloud Engine API ................ SUCCESS [3.927s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Framework - Security ............ SUCCESS [2.258s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Core ............................ SUCCESS [18.340s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Agents .......................... SUCCESS [6.946s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Framework - Clustering .......... SUCCESS [4.111s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Framework - Event Notification .. SUCCESS [1.263s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Cloud Engine Schema Component ... SUCCESS [12.014s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Framework - Jobs ................ SUCCESS [4.621s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Cloud Engine Internal Components API  SUCCESS [2.448s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Server .......................... SUCCESS [34.150s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Usage Server .................... SUCCESS [5.247s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Cloud Engine Orchestration Component  SUCCESS [7.926s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Cloud Services .................. SUCCESS [0.029s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Secondary Storage ............... SUCCESS [0.221s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Secondary Storage Service ....... SUCCESS [4.067s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Engine Storage Component ........ SUCCESS [5.103s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Engine Storage Volume Component . SUCCESS [3.416s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Engine Storage Image Component .. SUCCESS [1.988s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Engine Storage Data Motion Component  SUCCESS [2.026s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Engine Storage Cache Component .. SUCCESS [2.160s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Engine Storage Snapshot Component  SUCCESS [5.856s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Cloud Engine API ................ SUCCESS [1.439s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Cloud Engine Service ............ SUCCESS [3.501s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin POM ...................... SUCCESS [0.381s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - API Rate Limit ......... SUCCESS [5.112s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Storage Volume default provider  SUCCESS [2.032s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Storage Volume SolidFire Provider  SUCCESS [4.023s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - API SolidFire .......... SUCCESS [2.192s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - API Discovery .......... SUCCESS [3.353s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - ACL Static Role Based .. SUCCESS [1.870s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Host Anti-Affinity Processor  SUCCESS [2.430s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Explicit Dedication Processor  SUCCESS [2.099s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - User Concentrated Pod Deployment Planner  SUCCESS [1.766s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - User Dispersing Deployment Planner  SUCCESS [1.562s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Implicit Dedication Planner  SUCCESS [5.620s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Skip Heurestics Planner  SUCCESS [1.554s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Host Allocator Random .. SUCCESS [2.016s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Dedicated Resources .... SUCCESS [5.028s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Hypervisor OracleVM .... SUCCESS [2.520s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Open vSwitch ........... SUCCESS [2.586s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Hypervisor XenServer ... SUCCESS [7.608s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Hypervisor KVM ......... SUCCESS [7.350s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - RabbitMQ Event Bus ..... SUCCESS [1.861s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - In Memory Event Bus .... SUCCESS [3.026s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Hypervisor Baremetal ... SUCCESS [4.021s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Hypervisor UCS ......... SUCCESS [2.294s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Hypervisor Hyper-V ..... SUCCESS [4.920s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Network Elastic Load Balancer  SUCCESS [5.291s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Network Internal Load Balancer  SUCCESS [6.544s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Framework - Spring Life Cycle ... SUCCESS [1.831s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Network Juniper Contrail  FAILURE [2.055s]
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Palo Alto .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Network Netscaler ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Network Nicira NVP ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - BigSwitch Virtual Network Segment  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Network Brocade VCS .... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Midokura Midonet ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Stratosphere SSP ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Network Opendaylight ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Storage Allocator Random  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - User Authenticator LDAP  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - User Authenticator MD5 . SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - User Authenticator PBKDF2-SHA-256  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - User Authenticator Plain Text  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - User Authenticator SAML2  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - User Authenticator SHA256 Salted  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Dns Notifier Example ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Storage Image S3 ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Storage Image Swift provider  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Storage Image default provider  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Storage Image sample provider  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Storage Volume Nexenta Provider  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Storage Volume CloudByte Provider  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Storage Volume sample provider  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - SNMP Alerts ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Syslog Alerts .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - Network VXLAN .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Plugin - GloboDNS ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Framework - Spring Module ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Secondary Storage Controller .... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Console Proxy - RDP Client ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Console Proxy ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Console Proxy - Server .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack System VM ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Client UI ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Framework - QuickCloud .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Test ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Developer Mode .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack Developer Tools ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack apidocs ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack marvin .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack DevCloud ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache CloudStack DevCloud-KVM .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4:56.657s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Nov 01 15:35:45 CET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 73M/340M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project cloud-plugin-network-contrail: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.cloudstack:cloud-plugin-network-contrail:jar:4.5.3-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact net.juniper.contrail:juniper-contrail-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in internal-repository (http://192.168.1.109:8081/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :cloud-plugin-network-contrail
```

This is my .m2/settings.xml

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>internal-repository</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Manager running on Spielplatz</name>
      <url>http://192.168.1.109:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

When I deploy cloudstack without using my own repository, everything works fine, so I tried to copy the jar file that is required in the Hosted - SNAPSHOTS repository on nexus (by copying it into the /opt/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/snapshots and refreshing the repository in the web UI) but it won't work. The same error shows up.

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the repository configuration of `internal-repository` (i.e. `<repository>` element)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.. I don't know what repository configuration you exactly mean. The settings.xml is the whole thing file. Does it also need a repository section?

Answer (score 1):

Maven's output says it all:

```
[WARNING] The POM for net.juniper.contrail:juniper-contrail-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing,
  no dependency information available

...

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project cloud-plugin-network-contrail:
  Could not resolve dependencies for project
    org.apache.cloudstack:cloud-plugin-network-contrail:jar:4.5.3-SNAPSHOT:
      Could not find artifact net.juniper.contrail:juniper-contrail-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        in internal-repository (http://192.168.1.109:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)
```

This occurs since you:

> tried to copy the jar file that is required in the Hosted - SNAPSHOTS repository on nexus (by copying it into the /opt/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/snapshots and refreshing the repository in the web UI)

which is not one of the proper ways to do such:

- Using the [`deploy-file`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) goal of the [Apache Maven Deploy Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/).
- Using Nexus' UI to upload artifact(s) manually.

  See [Repository Management with Nexus, 5.13. Uploading Components](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-uploading.html).

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I also used the UI to upload the artefact manually but it didn't work either :'-(. I think it might be a problem with the settings.xml. As far as I understand, it should download the artefacts from the repository but if it doesn't find it, then should be download it from the internet and upload it to nexus, could it be that?

Comment: @Ramzendo What does „_didn't work either_“ mean? Was there a Nexus error message? Did you upload it to the correct repo? I've neither heard nor experienced that this upload doesn't work.

Comment: I uploaded the correct artefact into the 3rd party with the according POM and jar file. I have also added the proxy repositories from juniper-contrail both: snapshots and releases and I still get the error that the dependencies cannot be resolved.

Comment: @Ramzendo Have you tried to upload it to your _snapshots_ repo? Since it is, well, a `-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: What is weird is that without using nexus it works perfectly fine. I have copied the same repository url from the project pom but it doesn't even shows me the remote content.

Comment: by the way, this is the repository information:
`<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>juniper-contrail</id>
      <url>http://juniper.github.io/contrail-maven/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>`

Comment: @Ramzendo Have you ever had a look at https://github.com/Juniper/contrail-maven containing the repository URLs `https://github.com/Juniper/contrail-maven/raw/master/releases` and `https://github.com/Juniper/contrail-maven/raw/master/snapshots`? Which differ significantly from that what you mention.

Comment: of course... I have already tried those URLs. Same result. I'm using the url from the project code since is newer than those URLs.

Comment: Apparently https://github.com/Juniper/contrail-maven/raw/master/snapshots doesn't exist which is mean by Juniper. (Which fits to their Network Connect VPN client which is the worst VPN client I've ver had to work with.) Can't you use https://github.com/Juniper/contrail-maven/tree/master/releases/net/juniper/contrail/juniper-contrail-api/1.2?

Comment: Thanks, the url doesn't work. For those github urls I always get something like: `String index out of range: -10. Nexus returned an error: ERROR 500: Server Error`

Comment: Have you seen the [issue _contrail-maven repo is broken_](https://github.com/Juniper/contrail-maven/issues/5) which is open since 20 Jan? Forget this company.

Comment: That could be, but the weird thing is that using maven without nexus does the job. I can even see the jar file in .m2/repositories. How can it be that without nexus works and with it it doesn't?